# Excel 2013 - Power Query After Append Do Not Show Only One Table

Tags: excel-2013, powerquery

When Merging 2 tables, is there way to hide the appended table so you don't see it in the Workbook Queries pane?

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ2aX.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on this query -> "Load to..." --> select "Connection only".
No more load onto sheet, but still visible in queries pane